# PHP Session Variable lost after click on page other category

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I have one site such as OLX.com for used product buy and sell, index page has city filter drop down list, once user clicks filter he will see only product from his filter city and redirect to page `city_filter.php` till now everything is working, 
after city filter when user click on any categories such as computer or Electronics user not found any product, all categories are coming from mysql database, `city_filter.php` included `function_city.php` for calling function for all categories, please find `city_filter.php` function created on `function_city.php` as follow:

```
function displaycomputer_city(){

                global $con;
                $get_cats = "select * from categories where categories_id = 1";
                $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

                while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

                $computer_id = $row_cats['categories_id'];
                $computer_title = $row_cats['categories_name'];     

                echo "<li><a href='city_filter.php?computer_cat=$computer_id'>$computer_title</a></li>";

                }


        }
```

On `city_filter.php` page, when I click Computer it take on browser `computer_cat=id` and I am using mention function to filter computer only from filter City

```
function getcomputerpro_city() {

        global $con;
        global $eu;
        global $limit;  

        if(isset($_GET['computer_cat'])){               

            $cat_id = $_GET ['computer_cat'];   
$get_products = "SELECT product_list.*, city1.* FROM product_list INNER JOIN city1 ON product_list.city_id=city1.city_id AND product_list.city_id={$_SESSEION['city_id']} AND categories_id='$cat_id' limit $eu, $limit";

foreach ($con->query($get_products) as $row) {

echo "<div class='ser-grid-list'>
<h5>$row[product_title]</h5>
    <img src='admin_area/product_images/$row[image_1]' width='160' height='110' alt=''>
    <p>Price : $row[currency] $row[product_price]</p>
    <p>City : $row[city_name]</p>
    <p>Date : $row[date]</p>
    <div class='btn top'><a href='details.php?pro_id=$row[list_id]'>View More</a></div>
</div>";
}   
}       
}
```

I think I am not going with correct why, because what I noticed when I click on Computer categories it takes `computer_cat = id` which is on receive using GET method, and once click categories city id session is lost, I don't what is the practice for this type of situation.

Comment: $_SESSEION['city_id'] typo?

Answer (score 1):

If you have included `session_start();` in the start of every page and if you have not unset/destroyed sessions, you have a typo here:

> Change this:

```
$get_products = "SELECT product_list.*, city1.* FROM product_list INNER JOIN city1 ON product_list.city_id=city1.city_id AND product_list.city_id={$_SESSEION['city_id']} AND categories_id='$cat_id' limit $eu, $limit";
```

> to this:

```
$get_products = "SELECT product_list.*, city1.* FROM product_list INNER JOIN city1 ON product_list.city_id=city1.city_id AND product_list.city_id={$_SESSION['city_id']} AND categories_id='$cat_id' limit $eu, $limit";
```